# The new Form feature in Google Colaboratory

Tags: forms, user-interface, google-colaboratory

[image: the new form feature]

Can someone explain or give a notebook example how to use the new Form feature? It looks really exciting, but I cannot find any example or even an announcement anywhere.

Comment: I'm wondering why jupyter/jupyterlab still doesn't have such a feature (AFAIK).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Now there is an official example here:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb

Comment: As a side question are you guys aware of similar features for the more standard jupyter/jupyterlab notebooks?

Answer (score 13):

Exciting feature indeed. It seems we can use checkboxes and date fields:

```
boolean_checkbox = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
date_input = '2018-03-22' #@param {type:"date"}
```

but I would really love to be able to construct dropdown lists using existing variables. Currently this seems limited:

```
dropdown = '1st option' #@param ["1st option", "2nd option", "3rd option"]
```

To be clear I'd love to be able to write

```
countries = df['country'][0] #@param df.country.unique()
```

Anyone?

Comment: It seems that dropdowns, sliders and more are already available: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb#scrollTo=ad-fjFOQxoFG

Comment: Would be great if we could do this. Would change things a lot

Answer (score 7):

Here are all the possible types:

```
var_int    = 15           #@param {type:"integer"}
var_float  = 0.36         #@param {type:"number"}
var_bool   = False        #@param {type:"boolean"}
var_date   = "2018-10-21" #@param {type:"date"}
var_str    = "str"        #@param {type:"string"}
var_raw    = "raw"        #@param {type:"raw"}

var_slider = 39           #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:100, step:1}
var_enum   = "val1"       #@param ["val1", "val2", "val3"]
```

The types are pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Is there a way to write values on multiple lines, one value at a line. It is useful when you have a lot of choices like `#@param ["val1", "val2", ... "val99"]`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be an in-development feature. I noticed it a couple of days ago, on a refraction doc I was using in-class with students, and assumed it was because I'd imported matplolib, which I've not had reason to do before.

I reloaded the doc later to have a closer look, but the 'form' and 'field' buttons had disappeared from the mouseover menu.

I know I was not dreaming because the

## @title

attribute was still there!

I just opened an unrelated student doc now  to mark it and the additional menu items are there. No matplotlib in this doc, just basic Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's a useful and simple features to input values in Colab notebooks, still not described in Colab documentation.

For example I have a notebook to run instance segmentation of an image. To specify image url, before I had to modify a python variable like this:

```
image_url = 'http://example.com/image.jpg'
```

Now I can make a user friendly form field ("+field" button) with values:

- Variable name = image_url
- Variable type = string
- Form field type = input

Then switch to form visualization (dropdown near "+field" button) to visualize only form during notebook execution.