# How to use a variable as the input for a form field in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: forms, google-colaboratory

The official example shows how to use Form Fields in Google Colaboratory: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb.

Let's say we have a list: 
`fruit_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes']`

Now I would like to add the elements of this list as a dropdown in the Form:

```
#@title # Select Your Choice of Fruit
fruit_selected = 'apples' #@params fruit_list {input: string}
```

As of now I can think of some hacks like this one:

```
#@title Boolean fields { run: "auto", vertical-output: true }
this_list = ["False", "True"]
boolean_checkbox = False #@param {type:"boolean"}
boolean_dropdown_asis = False #@param ["False", "True"] {type:"raw"}
boolean_dropdown_var = this_list[1] #@param {type:"raw"}

print(boolean_checkbox)
print(boolean_dropdown_asis)
print(boolean_dropdown_var)
```

But I would prefer to have another type of input: variable instead of just raw/string. The final implementation could be like this:

```
#@title # Select Your Choice of Fruit
fruit_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes']
fruit_selected = 'apples' #@params fruit_list {input: variable}
```

> I worked on some [OVERKILL. You are free to look at it.](https://github.com/sugatoray/CodeSnippets/blob/master/src/Notebooks/Google_Colab_Forms_Overkill.ipynb) Comments are welcome! :)

Anyone, any better idea?

Notes: There is another [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165220/the-new-form-feature-in-google-colaboratory) where [Sergio Lucero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4650316/sergio-lucero) raised a similar question. But the main thread has a different question.

Answer (score 9):

If you use the widget like in the notebook of blois, you can use the following code to call the value:

```
fruit_picker.value
```

This will return the value of your chosen fruit.

The code in total will look like this:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
fruit_list = ['pomegranate', 'watermelon', 'lychee']
fruit_picker = widgets.Dropdown(options=fruit_list, value='watermelon')

fruit_picker

fruit_picker.value
```

Answer (score -6):

Your original code almost has the solution.
If you look carefully you will find it in the documentation.

Instead of

```
fruit_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes']
fruit_selected = 'apples' #@params fruit_list {input: string}
```

Use

```
fruit_selected = 'new' #@param ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes'] {allow-input: true}
```

And you will be able to choose from the list OR enter new elements.

[image]

If you want to input the name of an *existing variable*, you could do this

```
fruits=['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes']
other={"a": 1, "b": 2}

fruit_selected = 'b' #@param ['apples', 'bananas', 'mangoes'] {allow-input: true}

#---- Find it in a dictionary

if fruit_selected not in fruits:
  if fruit_selected in other:
    print(f'{other[fruit_selected]}')
  else:
    print("Fruit selected NOT in other")

#---- Find it by name

a="x2"

if fruit_selected in globals():
  print(f'Got {fruit_selected}')
```

But for this kind of interactions maybe ipywidgets is a better tool.

Comment: Not sure this really addresses the idea of hierarchical form fields.