# How to add form elements from an array in Colab

Tags: forms, google-colaboratory

I have trouble trying to use an array as elements of drop-down list. I tried to google it, but it only leaded me to the official document which list all the options, but my variables will dynamically change when you rerun the code. Thx in advance.

btw, I converted it to a list only because I saw one post saying a list works... but it doesn't work on my end...

[Here's my simple code. The last line need some fix.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUhgr.png)

Comment: xref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63117410/13697228, ipywidgets is probably the way to go for more involved form-style inputs